# how to set value of proj_id as max(proj_id) + 1 in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am trying to obtain value of max(proj_id)+1 and set the value in vo and then i am inserting the data to db. i am trying this in the following code but i am getting null pointer exception....

```
public final class CreateProjDAO 
{
private static InitialContext context;
String CLASS_NAME="DBConnectionFactory";
public void  submitProjectDetails(CreateProjVO createprojVO) 
{
    String methodname="createConnection";
    Connection conn  = null;
    PreparedStatement psmt;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement st=null;
    int proj_id;
    try {
        conn = DBConnection.getJNDIConnection();

        rs=st.executeQuery("select MAX(PROJ_ID) from CR_PROJECT_DETAILS");

        if(!rs.next())
        {   
            proj_id=rs.getInt(1)+1;
            System.out.println("Max:"+proj_id);
        }
        else
        {
            proj_id=1;
             System.out.println("Max:"+proj_id);
        }

         createprojVO.setId(rs.getString(proj_id));

        System.out.println("in DAO");

       psmt= conn.prepareStatement("insert into CR_PROJECT_DETAILS(PROJ_ID,PROJ_NAME,PROJ_COST,PROJ_MANAGER) values(?,?,?,?)");
            psmt.setString(1, createprojVO.getId());
            psmt.setString(2,createprojVO.getName());
            psmt.setString(3,createprojVO.getCost());
            psmt.setString(4,createprojVO.getManager());
            psmt.executeQuery();


        System.out.println("conn==="+conn); 
        conn.close();
         System.out.println("Disconnected from database");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.out.println("data already exist");
        System.out.println("error:"+e);

    } 

}
}
```

Comment: What exact line are you getting the NPE on?

Comment: and exception comes at which line ?

Comment: in the console i am just gettin this java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Haven't you mixed up the if-else clauses?

Comment: But I think you are asking the wrong question here. In almost all databases, there are mechanism for marking columns as auto-increment, which will accomplish  exactly what you are trying to do here in your Java code. Using this instead will make your code cleaner and less error prone. For example, your code could easily break in a multi-thread environment such as a web server if one thread queries the database for a project id but is switched out before it inserts the new project. Then another thread queries and gets the same id, and you will have a key constraint violation. 
What db use you?

Comment: i have no idea how to go about it can anyone tel me the other alternate method or verify my code and give the solution

Comment: @AndersG : i am using oracle db . i think i can solve this as u said i wil try it ....

Comment: Just google for "oracle" and "auto increment" and you should be good to go in no time.

Comment: Yes with the use of sequence to auto generate the ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rs=st.executeQuery("select MAX(PROJ_ID) from CR_PROJECT_DETAILS");
```

st hasn't been initialized when the statement is hit, thus a NPE occurs.